# Compare dates using ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a table containing column A of type "timestamp with time zone".

I want to get elements from this table having A >= now with timezone - 30 minutes

So I tried this code:

```
b = db.query(models.My_Class).filter(models.My_Class.A >= datetime.now(pytz.utc) + timedelta(minutes=-30)).first()
```

**Expected result:**

- getting a record if exist with a date respecting this condition
- getting none if no records respects this condition

**Actual result:**
I'm getting a record not satisfying the condition

Is there something wrong in my query?

Comment: How is the data model stored in your database? Are you using timestamps with timezone? What data do you have in the database for testing and what data are you using for testing?

Comment: What is the value of the field `A` in the row that gets returned? Have you compared that value with the result of `datetime.now(pytz.utc) + timedelta(minutes=-30)` by itself? (btw: `datetime.utcnow` might be what you're looking for, since what you're doing is converting the current, local datetime to utc -- not sure if that's what you meant to do?)

Comment: @MatsLindh, this is what i've tested yesterday 07 Mar 2022 night 22H

I'm getting a record with a field = 2022-03-06 23:55:26.313752+01 and the difference is more than 30 minutes but i will try it again with datetime.utcnow

Comment: You're querying with a utc timezone, but you have a non-utc time stored; you either want to store utc in the database (the preferred way) or query with the adjusted timezone (this might require that all your datetimes in the database has the same offset, depending on which database you're using)

Comment: @MatsLindh i created this field using alembic migration and i'm using postgres
sa.Column('a', sa.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
                              server_default=sa.text('now()'), nullable=False)

do you know how can i store utc in the db ? i thought is was using TIMEZONE = True